# Allow buttons to trigger new view controllers within a page view controller - swift

Tags: ios, swift, button, uipageviewcontroller

Currently, in my app, I have a page view controller setup. Within the page view controller, there are 3 different view controllers. Within the three view controllers, there are buttons. I want these buttons to be able to trigger the page view controller to go left or right.

So far I have tried adding a public function within my page view controller and calling it within another view controller like this:

Public Function:

```
public func nextViewController(vc: UIViewController) {
     HomeRootPageViewController().setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Called Function when button was hit in a different vc:

```
@IBAction func backButton(_ sender: Any) {
   HomeRootPageViewController().nextViewController(vc: SocialMediaFeedViewController())
}
```

When I run the code above I receive this error:

```
UICollectionView: must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter
```

Basically, I was wondering how I use a button to control the functionality of a UI pageview controller.

Comment: What happens when you do this?

Comment: I added the error message within the answer above. @Lou Franco

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you shouldn't be passing in a VC you make with the default init (SocialMediaFeedViewController()) -- is this in a storyboard?

If so, construct it with

```
 UIStoryboard(name: "SBName", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SocialMediaFeedViewController"))
```

If not, do it however you initialized it to begin with, or reuse it if you still have a reference to it.

Comment: I would do this but it doesnt give me the animation I want as it is within a page view controller

Comment: The code I gave you can be used to instantiate the VC and present it however you want.